# Prove that $L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R}) $ by $Vf(t) = f(t-1),$ is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-transformations, isometry

we define $V:L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R}) $ by $$Vf(t) = f(t-1).$$
Then I'd like to show that $V$ is an isomorphism

**Here's what I've got so far:**

$$\left \langle vf(t), vf(t)\right \rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t-1)\overline{f(t-1)} dt=\left \langle f(t), f(t)\right \rangle$$

so we have$$\|Vf\|=\|f\|$$ indeed, $V$ is one-to-one
and we can easily show that $V$ is linear

> How can I prove $V$ is surjective and $V^{-1}$ is continuous?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about finding the inverse of $V$?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown , is it possible to say that since $V$ is one-to-one so $V^{-1}$ is bounded?

Comment: One can say all sorts of things, but just writing down $V^{-1}$ explicitly is the easy way to proceed.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown, I get $V^{-1}f(t)=f(t+1)$ is it corect?

Comment: @user62498 Why not just prove it? Let $W: L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be your intended inverse. Show that $W$ is indeed a morphism between the spaces, i.e. an isometry. (I am always cautious writing $V^{-1}$ when indeed I have not yet proved its inverse status, so I'll stick to $W$.) Then prove $W \circ V = \mathrm{id}_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$ and $V \circ W = \mathrm{id}_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}
$. These two equations are the usual definition of isomorphism in many fields of math.

Comment: @ComFreek, I find $Wf=f(t+1)$ just I want to know is it correct?

Comment: Sorry, but that's not how math works. I get you might ask these questions in more complex settings, but here the proof is reasonably simple to carry out. (This assertion of mine implies correctness.)